# IP адрес контейнера неверный

Tags: docker, docker-compose, php-fpm

Есть конфигурация docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  nginx-server:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: sasol-nginx-server
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/etc/nginx:/etc/nginx
      - ./volumes/html/:/var/www/html
      - ./volumes/logs/:/var/log/nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - php-fpm
      - mysql-server
    networks:.
     - alexus-network
  php-fpm:
    container_name: sasol-php-fpm
    build: ./build/php7.4
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/html/:/var/www/html
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:.
     - alexus-network
  mysql-server:
    container_name: sasol-mysql-server
    build: ./build/mysql5.6.51
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./volumes/etc/mysql:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
    networks:
     - alexus-network
networks:
  alexus-network:
    driver: bridge
```

3 контейнера sasol-nginx-server, sasol-php-fpm и sasol-mysql-server
после запуска контейнеры получают следующие IP адреса

- sasol-nginx-server - 172.17.0.3 (виден извне как [www.example.com:8081](http://www.example.com:8081))
- sasol-php-fpm - 172.17.0.2
- sasol-mysql-server - 172.17.0.4

Все работало прекрасно.

В контейнере sasol-php-fpm был запущен cron task который делал http запрос к сайту [www.example.com:8081/script.php](http://www.example.com:8081/script.php) (то есть к контейнеру sasol-nginx-server - 172.17.0.3)   адрес клиента вызвавшего  script.php  определялся как 172.17.0.1 хотя по идее ожидался 172.17.0.2. Это был первый звоночек. Через некоторое время sasol-mysql-server стал определять подключаемых к нему клиентов как пришедших с 172.17.0.1, хотя подключения идут из контейнера sasol-php-fpm - 172.17.0.2.
То есть клиент [sasol-php-fpm - 172.17.0.2] пытается подключиться к [sasol-mysql-server - 172.17.0.4]. А mysql его отвергает считая что подключение идет с 172.17.0.1

ip адреса я проверял bash скриптом запущенным с хоста

```
a=$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' sasol-mysql-server)
echo sasol-mysql-server $a

a=$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' sasol-php-fpm)
echo sasol-php-fpm $a

a=$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' sasol-nginx-server)
echo sasol-nginx-server $a
```

Укажите хотя бы направление куда копать

Comment: Лучше вообще не копать. 172.17.0.1 - это адрес бриджа. Я вижу 2 варианта - либо прописать access на всю подсеть докера, либо просто переписать запросы на локалхост. На сколько я понимаю всё на одном хосте.

Comment: @WusikiJeronii Ваш вариант меня не устраивает. Моя конфигурация работала раньше. У меня созданы пользователи MySQL по именам хостов и сети без привязки к IP адресам. Хочу понять, это моя ошибка либо же проблема в docker. Спасибо за  ваше время.

Answer (score 0):

Надо жёстко прописать адреса. А не кто как определится и потом будет конфликтовать с не своими данными от прошлой работы.

Comment: @Иван в том и дело что я не хочу привязываться жестко к IP адресам. Я хочу использовать имена. Если мне нужно будет например встроиться в существующую конфигурацию то нужно уже менять  адреса у большего числа контейнеров и тогда начнется ад.